# How to dynamically add EC2 ip addresses to Django ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We've recently changed our deployment strategy to use AWS auto scaling group.

One problem we have in production is with the newly created EC2s.
Our Application starts to return:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 
    <ip_address>. You may need to add <ip_address> to ALLOWED_HOSTS`
```

because these EC2s are not in the original Django `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

It doesn't make sense for each newly created EC2 to have to redeploy; that contradicts the sense of "auto scale". 
Also, we don't want to use wildcards or IP range for security reasons.

What can we do?

Comment: why not use hostname?

Comment: The reason you cant just use the hostname is that typically there is a load balance healthcheck that needs to get through in order for the instance to be considered 'healthy' and added to the load balancer. This one does not use the hostname.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer was working fine with IMDSv1. In 2019 AWS launched IMDSv2 which requires session token authentication. Therefore, before requesting instance meta data we first need to fetch the token:

```
import requests

try:
    IMDSv2_TOKEN = requests.put('http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token', headers={
        'X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds': '3600'
    }).text
    EC2_PRIVATE_IP = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4', timeout=0.01, headers={
        'X-aws-ec2-metadata-token': IMDSv2_TOKEN
    }).text
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    EC2_PRIVATE_IP = None


ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'my-app-test.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com'
]

if EC2_PRIVATE_IP:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(EC2_PRIVATE_IP)
```

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-service.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

Comment: Thank you--this solution worked for me (AWS Linux 2 on Docker).  The Elastic Beanstalk health check is no longer showing 400 errors.

Answer (score 2):

The snippets below will find either the Public IP address or the Elastic IP address associated with your EC2 instance and append it to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

- Install PyCurl

  ```
  pip install pycurl
  ```
- Python 3

  ```
  import pycurl
  from io import BytesIO

  # Determine Public IP address of EC2 instance
  buffer = BytesIO()
  c = pycurl.Curl()
  c.setopt(c.URL, 'checkip.amazonaws.com')
  c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
  c.perform()
  c.close()
  # Body is a byte string, encoded. Decode it first.
  ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(buffer.getvalue().decode('iso-8859-1').strip())
  ```
- Python 2

  ```
  import pycurl
  from StringIO import StringIO

  buffer = StringIO()
  c = pycurl.Curl()
  c.setopt(c.URL, 'checkip.amazonaws.com')
  c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
  c.perform()
  c.close()
  # In Python 2, we can cast the return value to
  # string without knowing the exact encoding.
  ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(str(buffer.getvalue()).strip())
  ```