# Elastic Beanstalk Health Severe, failing with a code 400 -- even though I can visit my site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-elb

I have a Django application running on Elastic Beanstalk. I can visit my site no problem at `example.com`. I've set up automatic https redirect, so that it always directs to https. I've set it up so you can't view the site `example.elasticbeanstalk.com` domain -- if you go there you end up getting response code 400.

My auto scaling group is load balanced. My app is failing the health checks with status code 400, even though I can navigate to my site no problem with response code 200. My logs show:

`***amazon IP*** (-) - - [date] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 26 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"`

I'm guessing the error is either from

1. Not allowing connection at `example.elasticbeanstalk.com`
2. Haivng automatic HTTP -> HTTPS redirect (although that would come up with a 302 I'd guess)

When the Health Check pings a site, is it pinging your custom domain (`example.com`) or is pining the `elasticbeanstalk.com` domain? What can I do to either fix this or further diagnose the error? I'd rather not allow traffic at the `elasticbeanstalk.com` domain, because I don't think I can get SSL on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you recently migrated to Amazon Linux 2 and got hit with IMDSv2 then you have to use security token like this

```
import requests
EC2_PRIVATE_IP = None
try:
    security_token = requests.put(
        'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token',
        headers={'X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds': '60'}).text

    EC2_PRIVATE_IP = requests.get(
        'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4',
        headers={'X-aws-ec2-metadata-token': security_token},
        timeout=0.01).text
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    pass

if EC2_PRIVATE_IP:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(EC2_PRIVATE_IP)
```

Comment: great answer. Upgraded then was failing all health checks again. How'd you figure this out?

Comment: BTW -- don't forget to make this production only. On localhost, runserver will still work but will take 5 minutes!

Answer (score 9):

The reason this is failing is because the health check checks the EC2 instance private IP. This can change with ELB, so you need to dynamically get the private IP of the instance and add it to hosts. See [How to dynamically add EC2 ip addresses to Django ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277541/how-to-dynamically-add-ec2-ip-addresses-to-django-allowed-hosts)

```
import requests
EC2_PRIVATE_IP = None
try: EC2_PRIVATE_IP = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4', timeout=0.01).text
except requests.exceptions.RequestException: pass
if EC2_PRIVATE_IP: ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(EC2_PRIVATE_IP)
```

**(potentially) Bad Answer**

I found this answer at another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726032/django-and-elastic-beanstalk-url-health-checks/39922578). While it solves the problem, I do not think it is a good answer and may be insecure.

If you add this code to your `.ebextensions/something.config` file, it will redirect any requests from Health Checker with a certain status request to your domain.

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/eb_healthcheck.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        <If "req('User-Agent') == 'ELB-HealthChecker/2.0' && %{REQUEST_URI} == '/status/'">
            RequestHeader set Host "sub.example.com"
        </If>
```

Replacing `/status/` with what the health check url specified in `Config -> Loan Balancer -> Health Check Path`, and `sub.example.com` with your domain. They've also updated the health checker so it's `ELB-HealthChecker/2.0` now -- another thing to pay attention to.

HOWEVER: It may not be great for security reasons, I think this could be spoofed. If you were using the default `/` link, someone could spoof `ELB-HealthChecker/2.0` and then easily guess your link. I'm not very familiar with what someone could do with a `set Host` command, it may be harmless.

Comment: AWS Linux 1 only

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up.  I was running a multi-container Docker environment on AWS Linux 2 with Django on Elastic Beanstalk.  My environment was in a permanent severe state even though my app was accessible!  Thanks to the answers above, I learned that the health checks were occurring at addresses that were simply not the Elastic Beanstalk URL!  Also, the HTTP statuses were not visible on the EB environment health page, I had to go to the EC2 page and to the "target groups" health checks tab under load balancers to find out that my app was returning `400` codes to the health checks.  To quickly test the solution, I just added `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` (not good for production!) and sure enough, the issues disappeared!

I originally thought it was a Nginx issue and so I configured a Nginx container that worked with my Django app container.  Not sure if that's necessary anymore.  A totally frustrating and undocumented issue, but that comes with the territory of Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a quick "OK" via custom  middleware sufficient and lightweight.  This happens prior to the ALLOWED_HOSTS check.  If there's value in incorporating other health checks, then go for it.

```
# middleware.py
from django.http import HttpResponse

class HealthCheckMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Check for specific user agent and the root path
        if request.META.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT") == "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" and request.path == "/":
            # Directly return an OK response
            return HttpResponse("OK", content_type="text/plain")

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Then add this to the top of the MIDDLEWARE list in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  "middleware.HealthCheckMiddleware",
  ...
}
```